# How to search people?

Tags: search

I want to be able to search users like I search documents in my site. I know this is possible, I have used it over a several Sharepoint sites. But I couldn't get it working for my site.

I don't need My Site feature. All I want is to be able to search and view profiles of users.

Could you please give direction to this poor newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link will help you
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-people-search-lessons-learned-covering-basics/

Comment: Could you add some information on what the linked article is about, and how it may help, please? This is standard practice, and is to help people looking for similar answers later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using a coded solution you can look at using a FullTextSearchQuery also:

```
FullTextSqlQuery q = new FullTextSqlQuery(ServerContext.Current);
q.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
q.QueryText = "SELECT UserName, Email, PreferredName FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' AND Department = 'IT'";

ResultTableCollection tables = q.Execute();
ResultTable results = tables[ResultType.RelevantResults];
```

Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030854/sharepoint-user-profile-search).